# Is there a way to disable a dojox.mobile.switch?

Tags: javascript, dojo, disabled-control, dojox.mobile

Is there a way to disable a [dojox.mobile.Switch](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/mobile/Switch.html) so that it is visible but greyed out and unclickable/untouchable? I can't see anything in the standard API doc.

**Edit**: I should add that I am working with Dojo 1.7.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this? I've solved the greyed out issue by changing the opacity of the container but I don't see a way to disable the actual control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do this today. I extended the Switch module. Works well for me, but I'm sure it could be improved.

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojox/mobile/Switch"
], function(declare, Switch){
    return declare("my.package.Switch", [Switch], {

        disabled: false,
        events: {},

        disableSwitch: function() {
            //remove events (but hold on to them for later).. there may be a better dojo way of doing this
            this.events._onClick = this._onClick;
            this.events.onClick = this.onClick;
            this.events.onTouchStart = this.onTouchStart;
            this.events.onTouchMove = this.onTouchMove;
            this._onClick = function(){};
            this.onClick = function(){};
            this.onTouchStart = function(){};
            this.onTouchMove = function(){};

            //TODO: better styling to make it look disabled?
            // this.domNode.style.opacity = '0.5';
            this.domNode.style['-webkit-filter'] = 'grayscale(1)';

            this.disabled = true;
        },

        enableSwitch: function() {
            //reattach events
            this._onClick = this.events._onClick;
            this.onClick = this.events.onClick;
            this.onTouchStart = this.events.onTouchStart;
            this.onTouchMove = this.events.onTouchMove;

            // this.domNode.style.opacity = '1';
            this.domNode.style['-webkit-filter'] = 'grayscale(0)';

            this.disabled = false;
        }
    });
});
```